# How to query on related entities but return root entities?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, dql

This is a hypothetical question, because I'm trying to get my head around Doctrine ORM and having a hard time replicating what I'd do in plain SQL.

Suppose I have a simple ManytoMany relationship between tags and posts. They would map so that `Post::tags` is the owning side and `Tag::posts` is the reverse mapping.

I understand that with Doctrine's DQL I can select posts containing their tags, or tags referencing their posts with the following 2 queries

(1) `SELECT p, t FROM MyBundle:Post p JOIN p.tags t WHERE p.id = :id`

(2) `SELECT t, p FROM MyBundle:Tag t JOIN t.posts p WHERE t.id = :id`

But when I want to fetch posts by a number of tags, I have to choose between these:

(3) `SELECT p, t FROM MyBundle:Post p JOIN p.tags t WHERE t.value IN ('foo','bar')`

(4) `SELECT t, p FROM MyBundle:Tag t JOIN t.posts p WHERE t.value IN ('foo','bar')`

Both of these seem wrong.

With (3) I imagine the DB would scan the whole posts table before reducing the set to those tagged

With (4) I get a collection of tag objects back which is the inverse of what I'm after.

I tried the following, because logically it seemed to mirror what I'd do in SQL:

```
SELECT p, pt FROM MyBundle:Tag t JOIN t.posts p JOIN p.tags pt
                 WHERE t.value IN ('foo','bar') GROUP BY p.id
```

It doesn't work because Doctrine insists I select the root entity

**What's the best way to select on tags but get back unique posts as full objects?**

Comment: the numbers (3) and (4) made sense before my post was edited - I hope it's clear that they refer to the second set of example statements.

Comment: Edited the edit for you - now it makes sense again ;)

Comment: Can you do something like `SELECT p FROM MyBundle:Post p JOIN p.tags t WHERE t.value IN ('foo', 'bar') GROUP BY p.id`? What information from the entity you need in the final result?

Comment: Ideally I'd want fully hydrated posts with their tag collections, but that's not the main worry about my question. You've written my option 3 with the grouping I neglected to add. - how does this avoid scanning the entire posts table?

Comment: Your best bet might be to use the sql explain command and see what the generated sql actually does.  Then compare it to hand written sql.

Comment: Oh oops, didn't notice that. Now I understand your question more and Cerad's answer looks like the best way to go about it.

Comment: fair point about explain command, although I'm fairly certain selecting on posts will cause a whole table scan. I will do some tests, but really I'm curious about doctrine best practice for this kind of task.

Comment: Surely the query builder just lets you build up the DQL string programmatically.. which extra features does it offer that would solve this problem?

Comment: You can also try doing a subselect for the tags.  Something like: select * from post where post.id in (select post_id from tag where value in ('foo','bar')).  Seems like any decent query optimizer would be able to avoid a full scan.

Comment: Good call on the subquery. I'll have a go at that in Doctrine and report back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well the question, what you want is select all posts that have at least one tag whose value is in a defined set ("foo", "bar", ...) and ignore all other posts.

Let start from (3):

```
SELECT p, t FROM MyBundle:Post p JOIN p.tags t WHERE t.value IN ('foo','bar')
```

In MySQL this means approximately: "Select all posts having a tag whose value is either foo or bar".

However in DQL this means "Select all Posts and attach only tags whose values is either foo or or bar". Meaning that the query will return the set of all posts, but with tags filtered. This difference of behavior is due to the fact that doctrine has to create objects with the array returned by the Database Layer. When you make a MySQL query with JOINs, the results will be an array with duplicates. However, in the object world, duplicate posts have to be merged in a single Post object...

I believe the solution to your query is to filter when the join is made:

```
SELECT p,t FROM MyBundle:Post p JOIN p.tags t WITH t.value IN ('foo', 'bar')
```

you can understand the WITH DQL clause as if it added a condition in the ON MySQL clause. I.e. the above query is similar to MySQL query below:

```
SELECT p.*, t.* FROM posts AS p JOIN posts_tags AS pt ON pt.post_id = p.id JOIN tags AS t ON pt.tag_id = t.id AND t.value IN ("foo", "bar")
```

Remark that there is no more WHERE clause. The condition moved in the JOIN condition clause...

Hope this helps ;-)

Comment: Thanks for this. I get the WITH part, I hadn't thought of that. However, we're still scanning ALL posts aren't we? Is this not hugely inefficient?

Comment: If you create an index on the tags.value column (and of course other foreign key columns), the Database Management System (DBMS) will not scan the whole posts table and your query should be quite efficient.

Comment: Oh, I might not have well understood your last comment. I think we are not scanning all posts because the JOIN is an INNER JOIN (not a LEFT JOIN). Therefore, only the posts that have at least on joined tag entity should be selected. This is also why it was important to move the condition in the ON clause...

Comment: After running some EXPLAIN queries, I can see you're absolutely right. The joined condition results in exactly the same lookups as selecting on the tag to start with.